# tableView onRowRender sluggish with images

Tags: lua, coronasdk

So I am not sure if I am doing all wrong, please correct me if that's the case by telling me where I should place the code exactly.

I am adding 3 images on every row (display.newImage). It's working very well. The only issue is the scrolling is not fluid. Why is that? Are the images being redrawn every time a part of the table is out of view? How can I avoid that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the 60 FPS option to your `config.lua` document.  Tableview has always been fluid for me.